# What text size and color in Android Wear card

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-cards

I need to create a custom card. So its text should be the same as default in Android Wear cards. I use the next layout to create custom card

```
<android.support.wearable.view.CardFrame xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/card_text_not_on_golf_course"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.wearable.view.CardFrame>
```

Default text for Android wear cards:
[image]

In my app I receive the text:

[image]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the standard cards can be found in the [UI Toolkit](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/androiddevelopers/design/Android_Wear_Toolkit_20140722.pdf) available from [Design Download](https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html#Wear). Judging from it the `Title` is #a2a2a2 and the `Description` #434343. The font is either Roboto Light or the condensed version of it. I'd guess the font size is 20 sp but it could also be 16 sp.

I'm not able to verify currently but I would guess some of the `@android:style/TextAppearance` is mapped to these default styles.